# create dataframe with datetime hourly frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a pandas dataframe with first column as date + time and with hourly frequency.

So in the dataframe, it will be complete year date with hourly time i.e 365 * 24 = 8760 rows in the first column.

sample data output:

```
Hours
2018-01-01 00:00:00
2018-01-01 01:00:00
2018-01-01 02:00:00
...
...
...
2018-01-01 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `pd.date_range`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Hours': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01', freq='1H', closed='left')}
     )
```

#### Output:

```
                   Hours
0    2018-01-01 00:00:00
1    2018-01-01 01:00:00
2    2018-01-01 02:00:00
3    2018-01-01 03:00:00
...                  ...
8759 2018-12-31 23:00:00

[8760 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution !

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pandas.DatetimeIndex`.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(freq="h", start="2018-01-01", periods=365*24)
```

Then you can use that index when you create your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Arguments for `pd.DatetimeIndex()` have been updated.